# sys.aud$ got dropped how to rebuild it

Tags: sql, oracle, auditing

I had enabled auditing with oracle 12.2C and mistakenly dropped the table sys.aud$ 
is there anyway to recreate the same with the same columns I tried to create it again but it is not the same as the previous so unable to write the audit logs into it 
please let me know the solution for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition is stored in your installation. Head to:

```
$ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/admin/dsec.bsq
```

and you'll find the create table command that is needed. Extracting and re-running the relevant create table script is supported by Oracle (Doc 316452.1).

Here's the one from my 12.2 instance:

```
create table aud$                                       /* audit trail table */
( sessionid     number not null,                        /* server session id */
  entryid       number not null,           /* serial number to audit records */
  statement     number not null,                     /* sql statement number */
  timestamp#    date,            /* OBSOLETE: 10iR1 and above: time of query */
  userid        varchar2("M_IDEN"),                     /* database username */
  userhost      varchar2("M_HOST"),              /* client host machine name */
  terminal      varchar2("M_TERM"),                    /* client terminal id */
  action#       number not null,          /* action responsible for auditing */
  returncode    number not null,               /* return code for the action */
  obj$creator   varchar2("M_IDEN"),           /* schema where object resides */
  obj$name      varchar2("M_XDBI"),                    /* name of the object */
  auth$privileges varchar2(32),                        /* granted privileges */
  auth$grantee  varchar2("M_IDEN"),                      /* grantee username */
  new$owner     varchar2("M_IDEN"),        /* schema of the dependent object */
  new$name      varchar2("M_XDBI"),          /* name of the dependent object */
  ses$actions   varchar2("S_ACFL"),        /* success/failure of each action */
  ses$tid       number,                                         /* object id */
  logoff$lread  number,            /* number of logical reads in the session */
  logoff$pread  number,           /* number of physical reads in the session */
  logoff$lwrite number,           /* number of logical writes in the session */
  logoff$dead   number,                /* number of deadlocks in the session */
  logoff$time   date,                                    /* session duration */
  comment$text  varchar2("M_VCSZ"),  /* type authentication/trigger/protocol */
  clientid      varchar2(128),             /* user defined client identifier */
  spare1        varchar2(255),                               /* OS user name */
  spare2        number,             /* whether this table (aud$) is modified */
  obj$label     raw(255),                         /* OBSOLETE: 8.0 and above */
  ses$label     raw(255),                         /* OBSOLETE: 8.0 and above */
  priv$used     number,                              /* system privlege used */
  sessioncpu    number,                    /* total cpu time for the session */
  ntimestamp#   timestamp,                /* new timestamp (in UTC) of query */
  proxy$sid     number,                       /* proxy session serial number */
  user$guid     varchar2(32),                      /* global user identifier */
  instance#     number,                                   /* instance number */
  process#      varchar2("M_PIDL"),                         /* OS process id */
  xid           raw(8),                            /* transaction identifier */
  auditid       varchar2(64),                          /* audit operation id */
  scn           number,                                  /* SCN of the query */
  dbid          number,                 /* database identifier for source db */
  sqlbind       clob,                        /* bind variables for the query */
  sqltext       clob,                               /* sql text of the query */
  obj$edition   varchar2("M_IDEN"),                   /* Object edition name */
  rls$info      clob,                                    /* RLS related info */
  current_user  varchar2("M_IDEN")                           /* Current User */
)
/
```

Comment: thank you it is correct answer,but there is no button is shown to select it as correct answer